# Spark dataset write to parquet file takes forever

Tags: scala, apache-spark

spark scala App is getting stuck at the below statement and it's running more than 3 hours before getting timeout due to timeout settings. Any pointers on how to understand and interpret the job execution in the yarnUI and debug this issue are appreciated.

dataset
.repartition(100,$"Id")
.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.partitionBy(dateColumn)
.parquet(temppath)

I have a bunch of joins and the largest dataset is ~15 Million and the smallest is  < 100 rows.  I tried multiple options like increasing the executory memory and spark driver memory but no luck so far. Note  I have cached the datasets I am using multiple times and the final dataset storage level is set to Memory_desk_ser.

Not sure whether below executors summary this will or not

executors (summary)
Total_tasks     Input  shuffle_read shuffle_write
7749           98 GB   77GB         106GB

Appreciate any pointers on how to go about and understand the bottle based on the query plan or any other info.

Comment: Hey it is a question of spark code optimisation, please share y  code and your Logic ! So You can have a better response

Comment: here is sample. Dataset1 (few 100's rows),Dataset2 (less 100 rows),Dataset3(~ 8 rows),dataset4 ~50Million rows)
dataset5 = dataset4 cross join dataset3
dataset5 = dataset5 left joined with dataset1 and dataset2
dataset5= dataset5.with a bunch of new columns are added.udfs are being used. step:2
Dataset1 (few 100 rows) ,,Dataset2(~ 8 rows),dataset4 (~20Million rows)
dataset5 = dataset4 left joined with dataset1 , dataset2
dataset5= dataset5.with a bunch of new columns are added similar to above.step:3: dsfinal= step1.dataset5(union) step2.datasetset5
dsfinal.persist(memory_disk).

Comment: `.repartition` is a bitch. Try removing it, see if things improve.

Comment: Initially .repartition is not  there and its still taking time so as part of trying to optimize the write ,added the .repartition but still did not improve the perf.

Comment: Does using broadcast join hint while joining with smaller datasets help to speed up the query?. i will try but checking to see whether its going to make a difference

Comment: Seeing the exact code and the DAG(execution plan) created by spark would help. Furthermore since you are talking about some 10s of GB also knowing the platform (HW) on which you are running would help.

Comment: @novice8989 try to edit your answer with a piece of code representing what you are trying to do. Try to format it as code, with a monospaced font, so that everyone have an easier time trying to help you. Otherwise you will probably have some downvotes.

Comment: 1) did you rule out skew on the `id` column? 2) how many different `dateColumn` values are there?

Comment: Share ur code please

Comment: I am trying few different options will post the sample code later today